# KDE Network Manager Notification Options Not Available

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager, kde, notification

KDE Network Manager is suppose to have notification options for Connection Activated or Deactivated are missing here. I am on Kubuntu 14.04 LTS fully updated. You can see in the picture that some of the items are missing.

[image]

Comment: 'Connection Activated' or 'Deactivated' are shown by the 'Active connection state changed'.

Comment: Let's try that. I had been using KDE 4.14.x which has individual entries for `Connection Activated` or `Connection Deactivated`. What are those empty entries for?

Comment: @user26687 It works, thanks. Will you please convert that to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different version of the KDE Network Manager widget have various number of the notifications.

Kubuntu 12.04 LTS - KDE 4.8 has:

[image]

Kubuntu 14.04 LTS - KDE 4.13 has:

[image]

Kubuntu 15.04 - KF5 / plasma 5 has:

[image]

With the 14.04 LTS, KDE 4.13,the Connection Activated' or 'Deactivated' are shown by the 'Active connection state changed'.